# How to make the view above a UITableView dynamic?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a view on top of a tableviewController.  However, I want to make the view dynamic.
Current constraints aren't working.

[image: Not working, the view should be shorter in this example]

[image: Current constraints, is set on all four sides; I've tried removing the bottom constraints but the text view just goes off the screen]

What other approaches can I take to this?  My current constraints are on all four sides, I've tried removing the bottom constraint, but this has the view go off the screen instead of pushing the view controller down

The other alternative I thought of is to have the text view and table view on the same "level" (instead of imbedded) but then the table view is just scrolling instead of moving the entire screen.

Comment: Are you using the `tableHeaderView` for this?

Comment: Is that a `UITextView`? A text view does not have an intrinsic height because it's scrollable, you can however observe it's `contentSize` and update a height constraint.

Comment: No I'm just dragging and dropping a (view+text view) on top of of the tableview.  Is that the better route?

Comment: Are you wanting the textview to have a dynamic size based on its content? If not you could just set the height of the view to a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0):

**For Dynamic Text view**

In Storyboard / Interface Builder simply disable scrolling in the Attribute inspector.

In code `textField.isScrollEnabled = false` should do the trick.
But if in case it doesn't resolve your problem you can set bottom constraint like below

**Step1:** get a IB outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**Step2:** use the delegation method below.

```
extension NewPostViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
     func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
          textViewHeight.constant = self.textView.contentSize.height + 10
     }
}
```